# Current Price on Uniswap LP doesn't match Deposit Requirement

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3

I set the current price per apple as 4 grapes, so when I deposit 2 apples, wouldn't have to deposit 8 grapes. Why when I enter 2 apples it automatically enters ~4.22 as the recommended deposit for grapes?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The amount of tokens depend both on the current (starting) price and the min-max price range. See the Uniswap [documentation](https://support.uniswap.org/hc/en-us/articles/7423194619661-How-to-provide-liquidity-on-Uniswap-V3) for more information.

With price rage set from ~2 to around ~20 and starting price set to 4, you get the 2:4.22 relation. The exact number of tokens can be determined by the formular 6.29 and 6.30 from the Uniswap v3 [whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf).